# How to pass @foreach value into Bootstrap Modal? Laravel 7.3

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a list of categories, from where I want to pass `{{category.name}}` to data into Bootstrap modal.
I want to achieve that when I click on the specific button, to show the name of the category in the modal as a message?

**Categories**

```
    <div class="card mt-2">@foreach($categories as $category)
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ $category->name}}
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-2 float-right"
                        onclick="handleDelete({{$category->id}})">Delete</a>
                    <a href="{{route('categories.edit', $category->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-right">Edit</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @endforeach
     </div>
```

From where I've tried to pass {{$category->name}} into div element, but It showing the last element from the loop.

**Modal**

```
    <form action="" method="POST" id="deleteCategoryForm">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalCenterTitle"
                aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Delete category</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Are you sure you want to delete "{{$category->name}}" ?
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Go Back</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**JS Script**

```
     <script>
            function handleDelete(id){
                event.preventDefault();        
                var form = document.getElementById('deleteCategoryForm');
                console.log('Delete', form);
                form.action = '/categories/' + id;
                $('#deleteModalCenter').modal('show');
            }
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance